# Out of memory error when installing Moodle 2.2.2+

Tags: memory, installation, moodle

I'm trying to install Moodle 2.2.2+ in a shared 1and1 linux hosting with PHP 5.4, using the web installation (http://www.xxecotest3.ingles100.com).

When I executed the install for the first time, I could reach the step where it asks for the path of the moodledata folder location, and the step after that one (I don't remember exactly what that one was asking for, I believe the database info). After clicking to advance to the next step, I got this error:

**Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 8912896) (tried to allocate 73713 bytes) in /homepages/44/d######/htdocs/tests/moodle/lib/outputlib.php on line 626**

So I can't continue the installation. Also, even if I try to start the installation again from the beginning, I can't, I get the same error message.

I've also tried installing Moodle 1.9. I could get to the end of installation, and after clicking the last "next" (or "continue"), I got a blank screen. I turned on debugging in config.php and now it shows the same "out of memory" error...

I've just also checked the memory_limit value with phpinfo() and it's set to 90M, which I believe should be enough...

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to raise your PHP memory limit in the PHP configuration.

This is set raising the value of parameter "memory_limit" in PHP configuration file called php.ini

Comment: Actually I called 1and1 and apparently my real max memory was 30M, not the 90M that phpinfo() said. Luckily, I've been able to upgrade the hosting plan to one with 80M for the same price, and just now I finished the installation without any issues. Thank you!

Comment: Pay attention because you may need more memory depending on your Moodle size. Operations like automated backups, statistics calculation and grading calculation may need some more memory.